# Random freeze and crash

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash

I need your help troubleshooting something happening with my computer. 
For a while my computer has frozen for 20-40 seconds in a random fashion, usually when moving the seekbar on youtube videos or opening new chrome tabs. Everything just stops responding. I can move the mouse, click on already rendered elements but nothing happens. A moment later, the windows flash black and everything is back to normal.

Steam freezes to the point it needs to be restarted

I've also tried playing Destiny 2 (open beta weekend). The computer freezes and reboots almost less than 30 seconds into the game.

Upon booting (especially the first time in the day) it throws a "disk read error occured" randomly

What i've done so far:
Freshly formatted windows 10
New RAM, tested with windows memory diagnostic and memtest (not overnight)
Swapped disk from SSD to HDD. Both healthy according to SMART test
Disabled graphics card, sound card, watching for DPC latency check (It sits at around 1000uS)

Specs: https://valid.x86.fr/nid9vw

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "Swapped disk from SSD to HDD" Do you mean that you cloned the contents of the disk over to the hard drive ?  Or installed fresh on a hard drive?

Comment: Fresh installs!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ruled out the sata cable by replacing it. Turns out.. i had TWO faulty sata cables. The problem were the f cables.. What are the odds?